# Excel Filter in LastName, FirstName format

Tags: excel, vba

i have to filter from a spreadsheet that has thousands of rows. my reference for filtering will come from another spreadsheet. i will filter out just names by the way, however the reference list is in this format (lastname,firstname). all your help will be greatly appreciated.

if you have other ideas (create a formula, use VB, etc..) feel free to pitch in.

thank you.

Comment: Could you do the following (1) post an example/screenshot of both worksheets, (2) tell us exactly the action you want to take, and (3) post an example/screenshot of the intended result. Also, descriptions of any attempts you have made so far would be nice.

Answer (score -2):

Type your cells Reference in your spreadsheet data (through coding or by using formula) it will automatically comes in your reference list , then you can filter it.